# how to BinarySearch in condition?

Tags: c#

I have here this code to create ID Randome when calling and then add to the ArrayList, but I want to check if I already have same ID to dont added to ArrayList I have used BinarySearch to check Result 
but it look there Something wrong

```
    public delegate void DESetUp();

    public static DESetUp IdSetUP = delegate ()
    {
        ArrayList valID = new ArrayList();

        Func<int> getID = () => new Random().Next(1, 5);

        int Result = getID();

        if (Result == valID.BinarySearch(Result))
        {
            valID.Add(Result);
            Console.WriteLine("AddSuccessful");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AddFailed");
        }


        foreach (var item in valID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your id is : {0}", item);

        }
    };
```

Thank you

Comment: What about just using HashSet<int> if you don't want duplicates? or just do `foreach (var item in valID.Distinct())`

Comment: `BinarySearch` returns the location of the match, not the value of the match.  Read the documentation page, it tells you exactly how to distinguish between "item found at this location" and "location where you should put the item when adding it".  Also, use a generic collection and let ArrayList languish in the dustbin of history where it belongs.

Comment: what about  if (valID.BinarySearch(valID, Result))
            {
                valID.Add(Result);
                Console.WriteLine("AddSuccessful");
            }

Comment: cant convert  from int

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, it's a leftover from before generics.  Instead use `List<int>`

Comment: If you want to use BinarySearch you first need to be shure that the collections is ordered, a collection with the order 1,3,2,4,5 will faill when you search a value after the number 3. take care on this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

use List instead of ArrayList:
Always you need to sort the values with BinarySearch

```
        List<int> valID = new List<int>();

        Func<int> getID = () => new Random().Next(1, 10);

        int Result = getID();
        // here need to sort the list
        valID.Sort();

        if (valID.BinarySearch(Result) < 0) // if the position of value is lles than zero the value does not exists
        {
            valID.Add(Result);
            Console.WriteLine("AddSuccessful");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AddFailed");
        }
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for answering, but there is a mistake i call in Main IdSetUP like this IdSetUP(); but if i call it Again in Main 4 time it don't work right it is not check!!

Answer (score 0):

i have reached a great result

i have assisted delegate List

```
public class MainClass
{

                           //assist delegate List<int>
    public delegate void DESetUp(List<int> DLint);
                                          //assist delegate List<int>
    public static DESetUp IdSetUP = delegate (List<int> valID)
    {

        Func<int> getID = () => new Random().Next(1, 3);

        int Result = getID();

        // here need to sort the list
        valID.Sort();

        if (valID.BinarySearch(Result) < 0) // if the position of value is lles than zero the value does not exists
        {
            valID.Add(Result);
            Console.WriteLine("AddSuccessful");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AddFailed");
        }
        foreach (int item in valID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);


        }

    };




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //assist List<int> ID
        List<int> ID = new List<int>();

        //ADD delegate + List<int> + IdSetUP
        IdSetUP(ID);
        IdSetUP(ID);
        IdSetUP(ID);
        IdSetUP(ID);


    }

}
```

thank you all